# How to choose basis functions that contribute most efficiently per term?

Tags: computational-physics, approximations

I would like to approximate some positive, scalar function $f(x,y) > 0$ on a 2D field of finite size i.e. $x\in [a,b],y\in[c,d]$

I am familiar with the set of basis functions used in the Fourier series but using the Fourier series requires too many terms. Infinitely many.

Instead, I desire to find a collection of functions that can be used to approximate $f(x,y)$ with a "finite" number of terms.

How can I approximate $f(x,y)$ with a collection of functions $G(x)$ and $H(y)$ (see definition of G and H below), such that the number of elements in $G$ or $H$ is finite?

$$G(x) = [g_1(x) ... g_n(x)], H(y) = [h_1(y) ... h_n(y)]$$

The elements in G and H do not have to be of the same form ($g_1(x) = sin(nx),g_2(x) = sin(mx)$).

(This question seems just like math, but I plan to use in a physical setting, which requires the superposition of electrical signals)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a certain way to numerically compute/represent a function, not about physics.

Comment: Answering this question helps me to move forward on an idea that involves displaying images on an led/lcd display using a method other than lighting up each pixel seperately. I thought the relationship to a physical system might warrant posting here. If you guys don't think so, I respect your choice to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you need to analyze your function f(x).

The benefit of the Fourier series is that the sinusoids are eigengfunctions of the wave equation (in cartesian space). So if your f(x) is describing a system that evolves according to the wave equation, then it will make the analysis easier if you represent f(x) in terms of the sinusoids.

If your system evolves according to some other differential equation, there is likely a more convenient set of basis functions you could use to represent inputs to that system.

If you just want to represent some particular f(x) with the least number of terms, then make f(x) one of the members of your basis set, and you're done. You can then represent your f(x) with a single term.

Comment: The functions that I want to approximate are scalar functions in R2. As for the structure of these functions, they are images.Apologies for not specifying. Thank you for saying something.

Comment: @ElecEng2016, without knowing what processing you will be doing on your approximated functions, there's no way to know what's the preferred basis set. Also, your question might get more traction in [Digital Signal Processing SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ElecEng2016, You might also look into [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) as a way to reduce the basis of a function [or set of functions] without presupposing the basis set. How it is extended to 2-d functions is beyond my expertise though.

Comment: Ok, I'll check out that stack exchange page. I'm pretty new to stackexchange so I didn't know it existed:) Also, I'll investigate how svd help my problem. Thanks for the advice.